# maximum likelihood with conditional distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, conditional

Let $(y_i,x_i),(i=1,...,n)$ be observations with $y_i|x_i \sim iidN(0,\sigma^2(\theta,x_i))$.

I want to estimate $\theta$ by maximum likelihood. But I cannot derive the likelihood function.
If $x_i$ is absent in $\sigma^2(\theta,x_i)$, i.e., $\sigma^2(\theta)$, the derivation of the likelihood is straightforward. But I don't understand how to deal with $x_i$ in $\sigma^2(\theta,x_i)$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so $\sigma^2$ is a function of $\theta$ and $x_i$? Do we know anything about this function?

Comment: Although it seems complicated at the beginning, the calculation, I think, is still straightforward as the likelihood is now a function of $\theta$. Just follow the normal density.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, $\sigma^2$ is function of $\theta$ and $x_i$ such that $\sigma^2(\theta, x_i)=\theta_1 x_i^2+\theta_2>0$.

Comment: Then, is the log likelihood given by $\log L(\theta)= -\frac{n}{2} \log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \log \sigma^2(\theta,x_i)-\frac{1}{2} \frac{x_i^2}{\sigma^2(\theta,x_i)} $?

Comment: Sorry, the last term is $-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2}{\sigma^2(\theta,x_i)}$.